# Chained subscription to an array of observables using rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an array of files I would like to upload (or at least *try* to upload, individual failure is OK) in Angular 5, one at a time, and then know when all the subscriptions have completed.

In the old days of Javascript I would have done this using chained callbacks, but since we have great tools like `rxjs` now, I get the sense that there is a better, more 'reactive' way to do this.

So: **what is the best way to do this with rxJS?**

I have an Angular provider which uploads a single file and returns an Observable; I would like to try to upload each file in the array individually and know when they have all completed.

In my example below, I have replaced the provider with a simple Subject that completes with a random success or error after a random amount of time, trying to emulate a shaky Internet connection.

**Problem:** When I use Observable.combineLatest(), I only get a final result when ALL Observables have next()ed a result: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`. If not all the Observables complete, I never get a result at all.

Furthermore, the Observables don't get run one at a time, but rather all at once. When used with an AJAX request, it could overload a cell connection.

Any thoughts on how to approach this?

```
constructor() {
    let observables = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        observables.push(this.testObservable(i));
    }


    Observable.combineLatest(observables)
        .subscribe(res => {
            console.log('success', res);
        }, err => {
            console.log('errors', err);
        })
}



testObservable(param) {
    let subject = new Subject;

    let num = Math.random() * 10000;
    console.log('starting', param)
    setTimeout(() => {

        if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
            console.log('success', param);
            subject.next(param);
        } else {
            console.log('error', param);
            subject.error(param);
        }

        subject.complete();
    }, num);

    return subject;
}
```

Comment: `If not all the Observables complete, I never get a result at all.`  What do you want to do in this case?  Give up after some amount of time?  Shouldn't your upload fail at some point?  Also, you state that you don't like `combineLatest` because you don't get a result until all finished.  Would you prefer to get a result as each one finishes?  Or would you prefer to get a result every X seconds whether or not any change has happened?

Comment: I would like to know when all the Observables have completed, regardless of whether they 'resolved' with a value or not. The idea is to know when to provide feedback to the user that the process has completed, one way or another. Is this just not the RxJS way? I may need to rethink my design.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `combineLatest` to wait for an array of Observables to complete. It will emit once each Observable it is supplied has emitted at least once.

```
let files = [uri1, uri2, uri3];
const observables = files.map(file => this.addMedia({ uri: file, post_id: res.post.Post.id }));

Observable.combineLatest(observables).subscribe(() => console.log('All complete'));
```

If you want the Observables to execute one after another you can use `concat` (for ordered) or `merge` if the order is not important.

In order to catch errors you can add a `catch` operator to each Observable and return an empty Observable or something more appropriate.

```
this.addMedia({ uri: file, post_id: res.post.Post.id })
    .do(val => console.log(`emitting: ${val}`))
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(`error: ${err}`);
      return Observable.empty();
    });
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that all the Observables get subscribed at once, which could overload a network connection.

Comment: Also, if some of the Observables never emit a next() because of an error, then the resulting Observable never completes.

Answer (score 0):

The child observables should either emit a `next()` or they should throw an error.  In both cases the child observable should complete.  If the child observable is not completing then you have a bug in your child observable.  If you know the child observable has a bug and will not ever complete then you can use a timeout but you really shouldn't have to do this.

Since errors in the child observables are fine you should catch them.  Lastly, if you want to buffer the items so they aren't sent to the server all at once then you can do that too.

Putting it all together ([RxJS Playground Link](https://rxjs-playground.github.io/#/?js=const%20start%20%3D%20Date.now%28%29%3B%0A%0Afunction%20elapsed%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20Date.now%28%29%20-%20start%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20dummyObservable%28delay%2C%20error%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20An%20observable%20that%20fails%0A%20%20if%20%28error%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20Rx.Observable.throw%28error%29%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20An%20observable%20that%20succeeds%20after%20some%20amount%20of%20time%0A%20%20if%20%28delay%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20Rx.Observable.create%28observer%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log%28elapsed%28%29%20%2B%20%27%3A%20Request%20to%20server%20emitted%27%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20setTimeout%28%28%29%20%3D%3E%20observer.next%28%29%2C%20delay%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%29%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20An%20observable%20that%20never%20completes%20%28you%20really%20shouldn%27t%20have%20these%29%0A%20%20return%20Rx.Observable.create%28%28%29%20%3D%3E%20%7B%7D%29%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20formatResult%28result%29%20%7B%0A%20%20if%20%28result.failed%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%27FAIL%28%27%20%2B%20result.error%20%2B%20%27%29%27%3B%0A%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%27PASS%27%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20obs1%20%3D%20dummyObservable%281000%29%3B%0Aconst%20obs2%20%3D%20dummyObservable%28500%29%3B%0Aconst%20fails%20%3D%20dummyObservable%28null%2C%20new%20Error%28%27This%20one%20fails%27%29%29%3B%0Aconst%20neverFinishes%20%3D%20dummyObservable%28%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20observables%20%3D%20%5Bobs1%2C%20obs2%2C%20fails%2C%20neverFinishes%5D%3B%0A%2F%2F%20We%20only%20want%20the%20first%20response.%20%20Only%20needed%20if%20your%20source%20observables%20aren%27t%20completing%20after%20emitting%20one%20item%0Aconst%20firstOnly%20%3D%20observables.map%28obs%20%3D%3E%20obs.first%28%29%29%3B%0A%2F%2F%20Only%20allow%205%20seconds%20and%20abort%20if%20no%20response%20after%205%20seconds%0Aconst%20timeoutsHandled%20%3D%20firstOnly.map%28obs%20%3D%3E%20obs.timeout%285000%29%29%3B%0A%2F%2F%20If%20any%20failures%20occur%20then%20handle%20them%0Aconst%20failuresHandled%20%3D%20timeoutsHandled.map%28obs%20%3D%3E%20obs.map%28%28%29%20%3D%3E%20%28%7B%20failed%3A%20false%20%7D%29%29.catch%28%28err%29%20%3D%3E%20Rx.Observable.of%28%7B%20failed%3A%20true%2C%20error%3A%20err%20%7D%29%29%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20buffered%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0A%2F%2F%20Buffer%20the%20request%20so%20200%20ms%20pass%20between%20each.%0Afor%28let%20i%20%3D%200%3B%20i%20%3C%20failuresHandled.length%3B%20i%2B%2B%29%20%7B%0A%20%20const%20delay%20%3D%20i%20%2A%20200%3B%0A%20%20buffered.push%28Rx.Observable.of%28%5Bnull%5D%29.delay%28delay%29.first%28%29.switchMap%28%28%29%20%3D%3E%20failuresHandled%5Bi%5D%29%29%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20combined%20%3D%20Rx.Observable.combineLatest%28buffered%29%3B%0Acombined.first%28%29.subscribe%28%0A%20%20%28values%29%20%3D%3E%20console.log%28elapsed%28%29%20%2B%20%27%3A%20values%3A%20%27%20%2B%20values.map%28v%20%3D%3E%20formatResult%28v%29%29%29%2C%0A%20%20err%20%3D%3E%20console.log%28err%29%0A%29%3B%0A)):

```
const start = Date.now();

function elapsed() {
  return Date.now() - start;
}

function dummyObservable(delay, error) {
  // An observable that fails
  if (error) {
    return Rx.Observable.throw(error);
  }
  // An observable that succeeds after some amount of time
  if (delay) {
    return Rx.Observable.create(observer => {
      console.log(elapsed() + ': Request to server emitted');
      setTimeout(() => observer.next(), delay);
    });
  }
  // An observable that never completes (you really shouldn't have these)
  return Rx.Observable.create(() => {});
}

function formatResult(result) {
  if (result.failed) {
    return 'FAIL(' + result.error + ')';
  } else {
    return 'PASS';
  }
}

const obs1 = dummyObservable(1000);
const obs2 = dummyObservable(500);
const fails = dummyObservable(null, new Error('This one fails'));
const neverFinishes = dummyObservable();

const observables = [obs1, obs2, fails, neverFinishes];
// We only want the first response.  Only needed if your source observables aren't completing after emitting one item
const firstOnly = observables.map(obs => obs.first());
// Only allow 5 seconds and abort if no response after 5 seconds
const timeoutsHandled = firstOnly.map(obs => obs.timeout(5000));
// If any failures occur then handle them
const failuresHandled = timeoutsHandled.map(obs => obs.map(() => ({ failed: false })).catch((err) => Rx.Observable.of({ failed: true, error: err })));

const buffered = [];
// Buffer the request so 200 ms pass between each.
for(let i = 0; i < failuresHandled.length; i++) {
  const delay = i * 200;
  buffered.push(Rx.Observable.of([null]).delay(delay).first().switchMap(() => failuresHandled[i]));
}

const combined = Rx.Observable.combineLatest(buffered);
combined.first().subscribe(
  (values) => console.log(elapsed() + ': values: ' + values.map(v => formatResult(v))),
  err => console.log(err)
);
```